# JPEG2000 Image Mosaic with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, gdal, jpeg-2000, hot-spot, jboss

Using GeoServer 2.8.4, I have been successful at creating JPEG2000 image mosaics with OpenJDK 1.7.0. I use the gdal plugin and jp2k plugin and JPEG2000 images are loaded with Kakadu. I explicitly set `it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.jp2k.JP2KKakaduImageReaderSpi` when creating the Image Mosaic.

As far as I know, the JPEG2000 coverage store is made available by the GDAL plugin which uses other plugins, in this case the JP2K plugin.

But now I need to switch from OpenJDK 1.7.0 to Java HotSpot JRE 1.8.0 and I get the following message when creating the layer:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Illegal grid range [0 .. -33,793] for dimension 0. : Illegal grid range [0 .. -33,793] for dimension 0.
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Illegal grid range [0 .. -33,793] for dimension 0.
cause-exception     : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
cause-message       : Illegal grid range [0 .. -33,793] for dimension 0.
class               : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
required-type       : org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridGeometry2D
converter-type      : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$GridGeometry2DConverter
line number         : 48
class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageInfoImpl
converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$CoverageInfoConverter
version             : 2.8.4
-------------------------------
```

Logs don’t show any error prior to this one. And logs don’t show any relevant difference between OpenJDK and HotSpot JRE.

I should mention that GeoServer runs under WildFly 8.2.0 and, besides this issue, everything works like a charm with HotSpot JRE 1.8.0.

Comment: Any update about this with geoserver 2.16 and Gdal 2.2 on Ubuntu?

Comment: @GloriP. Tested with GeoServer 2.16.2 / GDAL 2.2.4 (recompiled manually) / OpenJDK 1.8.0 / WildFly 18.0.1 / CentOS 7.6. This works when creating a JP2KAK coverage store. The key component is GeoServer 2.16 because it still crashed with GeoServer 2.15.