# How to use Image mosaic with JPEG2000

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, jpeg-2000

I am running GeoServer 2.16 with GDAL 2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I would like to use Image mosaic with Sentinel data on *.jpg2 format. 
I have already seen [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234179/jpeg2000-image-mosaic-with-geoserver) but it is referring to another version than I am using.

Following [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html), I have downloaded the GDAL Extension and but I think I need GDAL native library for reading JPEG2000 because Image mosaic is not able to read jp2 extensions.

Following the stores present on my local installation of GeoServer. 
I see JP2K(Direct) for reading .jp2 file format.

[image: list of stores present on my local version of GeoServer]

But this extension is not working. Maybe because I am missing [Kakadu](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/JP2KAK) (which is a proprietary software so I'll exclude it)?

Following the output of `gdal-config --formats`

```
gxf gtiff hfa aigrid aaigrid ceos ceos2 iso8211 xpm sdts raw dted mem jdem envisat elas fit vrt usgsdem l1b nitf bmp airsar rs2 ilwis rmf leveller sgi srtmhgt idrisi gsg ingr ers jaxapalsar dimap gff cosar pds adrg coasp tsx terragen blx msgn til r northwood saga xyz hf2 kmlsuperoverlay ctg e00grid zmap ngsgeoid iris map cals safe sentinel2 derived prf mrf webp epsilon wcs wms plmosaic wmts dods grib bsb openjpeg netcdf hdf5 hdf4 ogdi gif jpeg png pcraster pcidsk rik ozi pdf rasterlite mbtiles postgisraster arg
```

I've really stacked about this and I have no idea how to upload GeoServer image in GeoServer.

I am not able to download other plugin libraries (https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/gdal_format.html )

Comment: does your gdal install work with jp2k? if not then there is nothing GeoServer can do

Comment: I can query my *.jpg2 file with  `gdalinfo`

Comment: When I did the same, I found it much easier to convert `.jp2` (JPEG2000) to `.tiff` (GeoTIFF) and then joining the `.tiff` rasters. Both `gdal_merge.py` and `rasterio` would throw errors when I tried joining `.jp2` images. You can read more [about this here](https://wsdookadr.github.io/posts/p5/#_summary_of_the_full_algorithm).